# Kahler-Einstein metrics on Toric manifolds are Torus-invariant?

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, toric-varieties

let $(M,\omega)$ be a Kahler-Einstein toric manifold  of complex dimension $m$. By toric manifold i mean a manifold that has an open dense subset $X$ biholomorphic to an algebraic torus $\mathbb{T}^{m}:=( \mathbb{C}^{*})^{m}$   and  there is a holomorphic action 
\begin{equation}
\alpha:\mathbb{T}^{m}\times M\rightarrow M
\end{equation}
that on $X$ restricts to the standard action of $\mathbb{T}^{m}$ on itself. My question is the following: is the Kahler Einstein metric $\omega$ automatically invariant under the action of $\mathbb{T}^{m}$? If it is a known result can someone tell me a reference?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, the Fubini-Study metric on $\mathbb P^1$ is already not invariant under the torus action.

Comment: Your notation is causing some confusion because you are confusing the algebraic torus with the compact subgroup $K$ generated by the $S^1$-subgroups of the $\mathbb{C}^\ast$-factors, and $K$ is a topological torus.  Generally, one asks that the toric metric be invariant under $K$, not the whole (noncompact) algebraic torus, which is much more reasonable.

Comment: @Robert: If i consider the action of the compact subgroup $K$  is $\omega$ K-invariant? Are there obstructions?

Answer (score 3):

I would put this in the comments if I could. I think you will find the answer to your question here (I cannot access this paper):

Y. Matsushima: Sur la structure de groupe d'homeomorphismes analytiques d'une
certaine variete kaehlerienne, Nagoya Math. J. 11 (1957), 145-150.

as quoted in Theorem 2.4 in

T. Mabuchi: Einstein-Kähler forms, Futaki invariants and convex geometry on toric Fano varieties

Comment: I believe Matsushima's paper is open access here https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.nmj/1118799867 and Mabuchi's paper is also open access here http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ojm/1200780355